# Get values from in_array statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array filled with the result of a query which is as follows:

```
$ticket[] = array( 
    'ticket_id' => $row->ticket_id,
    'user_id' => $row->user_id,
    'raffle_ticket_num' => $row->raffle_ticket_num
);
```

Now, in a while loop, I check in all arrays inside $tickets if my variable $number equals 'raffle_ticket_num'. I do this with the following code (from @Fuzzy Tree):

```
$ticket_num=1;

while ($ticket_num <= $total_slots){

    foreach($ticket as $test) {
        if($test['raffle_ticket_num'] == $ticket_num) { 
             echo $ticket_num.' claimed by '.$test['user_id'];
          }

        else{
             echo $ticket_num;
            }   

    }

$ticket_num++;
}
```

The problem that I'm having now is that because I'm using a foreach loop, if more than one results are found, it causes it to echo each result as much as there are rows in $ticket[]... So with 2 rows it echos everything 2 times (because of the foreach). Does anyone know a solution or alternatives for this?

You can see it live here: http://tinyurl.com/hxbhx7y .The bold numbers are slot 21 and 38 which are taken and showing the user_id (1). But as you can see it shows each number 2 times (because foreach has 2 results)

**EDIT**: Post updated with @Fuzzy Tree's answer

Comment: just use a `foreach` like the one below, should suffice

Comment: Can you give small data sample that goes in, what you expect to get and wrong result?

Comment: Yeah sure. Check it out here: http://tinyurl.com/hxbhx7y . The bold numbers are slot 21 and 38 which are taken and showing the user_id (1). But as you can see it shows each number 2 times (because foreach has 2 results)

Comment: Can same ticket number be owned by 2 users?

Comment: Assumed that answer is no and updated my answer with solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Version 1**
`foreach` see answer by @FuzzyTree

**Version 2**
`array_filter`

```
$number = 1;
$winners = array_filter($tickets, function ($ticket) use ($number) {
    return $ticket['raffle_ticket_num'] == $number;
});

// $winners now has all winning tickets.
var_dump($winners);

// Bonus pick a random winner
shuffle($winners);                                                          
var_dump(current($winners));
```

So best and easiest way to do it prepare your tickets array outside of raffles loop.
**Solution**

```
<?php

$tickets[] = array(
    'ticket_id' => 1,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'raffle_ticket_num' => 15
);

$tickets[] = array(
    'ticket_id' => 2,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'raffle_ticket_num' => 25
);

$tickets[] = array(
    'ticket_id' => 3,
    'user_id' => 1,
    'raffle_ticket_num' => 21
);

$raffles = range(1, 50);

// Preparing tickets array. Now when I think Flattened is not the best word to describe it :)
$ticketsFlattened = array();
foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    $ticketsFlattened[$ticket['raffle_ticket_num']] = $ticket;
}

// Could be while if you want
foreach ($raffles as $number) {
    if (array_key_exists($number, $ticketsFlattened)) {
        echo sprintf(
            "Ticket %s is clamed by %s, ticket id %s %s",
            $number,
            $ticketsFlattened[$number]['user_id'],
            $ticketsFlattened[$number]['ticket_id'],
            PHP_EOL
        );

    } else {
        echo sprintf("Ticket %s unclaimed %s", $number, PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print the matching `user_id` and `ticket_id` then use a `foreach` to check each ticket one by one and when you see a ticket with the matching #, you can print the other details

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    if($ticket['raffle_ticket_num'] == $number) {
        print 'In array';
        print $ticket['user_id'];
        print $ticket['ticket_id'];
        //break; //uncomment if you just want one
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add `foreach($tickets as $key => $ticket)` If keys required for some other purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the problem with using foreach in my case is that it is used in a while loop, which causes it to print each result as much as there are results in total from the query... So with 2 results it prints each result 2 times. See my updated post above